# Python & Pygame- ValueError: empty range for randrange() ? Everything was working fine

Tags: python, module, pygame

the code was working fine, i didnt touch it and as i went to run it again i got 'ValueError: empty range for randrange()' error.. I didnt even touch the code and now i keep getting this error.. Its my platform game for my assessment task.. can anyone help please?

```
File "D:\Software major project\mainx.py", line 213, in <module>
g.new()
File "D:\Software major project\mainx.py", line 53, in new
c = Cloud(self)
File "D:\Software major project\spritex.py", line 131, in __init__
self.rect.x = randrange(WIDTH - self.rect.width)
 File "C:\Python34\lib\random.py", line 186, in randrange
raise ValueError("empty range for randrange()")
ValueError: empty range for randrange()
```

This is the spritex.py code

```
    import pygame as pg
    from settingsx import *
    from random import choice, randrange
    vec = pg.math.Vector2

class Spritesheet:
    # utility class for loading and parsing spritesheets
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.spritesheet = pg.image.load(filename).convert()

    def get_image(self, x, y, width, height):
    # grab an image out of a larger spritesheet
    image = pg.Surface((width, height))
    image.blit(self.spritesheet, (0, 0), (x, y, width, height))
    image = pg.transform.scale(image, (width // 2, height // 2))
    return image

class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game):
        self._layer = PLAYER_LAYER
        self.groups = game.all_sprites
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        self.walking = False
        self.jumping = False
        self.current_frame = 0
        self.last_update = 0
        self.load_images()
        self.image = self.standing_frames[0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (40, HEIGHT - 100)
        self.pos = vec(40, HEIGHT - 100)
        self.vel = vec(0, 0)
        self.acc = vec(0, 0)

def load_images(self):
    self.standing_frames = [self.game.spritesheet.get_image(614, 1063, 120, 191),
                            self.game.spritesheet.get_image(690, 406, 120, 201)]
    for frame in self.standing_frames:
        frame.set_colorkey(BLACK)
    self.walk_frames_r = [self.game.spritesheet.get_image(678, 860, 120, 201),
                          self.game.spritesheet.get_image(692, 1458, 120, 207)]
    self.walk_frames_l = []
    for frame in self.walk_frames_r:
        frame.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.walk_frames_l.append(pg.transform.flip(frame, True, False))
    self.jump_frame = self.game.spritesheet.get_image(382, 763, 150, 181)
    self.jump_frame.set_colorkey(BLACK)

def jump_cut(self):
    if self.jumping:
        if self.vel.y < -3:
            self.vel.y = -3

def jump(self):
    # jump only if standing on a platform
    self.rect.y += 2
    hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.platforms, False)
    self.rect.y -= 2
    if hits and not self.jumping:
        self.game.jump_sound.play()
        self.jumping = True
        self.vel.y = -PLAYER_JUMP

def update(self):
    self.animate()
    self.acc = vec(0, PLAYER_GRAV)
    keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pg.K_LEFT]:
        self.acc.x = -PLAYER_ACC
    if keys[pg.K_RIGHT]:
        self.acc.x = PLAYER_ACC

    # apply friction
    self.acc.x += self.vel.x * PLAYER_FRICTION
    # equations of motion
    self.vel += self.acc
    if abs(self.vel.x) < 0.1:
        self.vel.x = 0
    self.pos += self.vel + 0.5 * self.acc
    # wrap around the sides of the screen
    if self.pos.x > WIDTH + self.rect.width / 2:
        self.pos.x = 0 - self.rect.width / 2
    if self.pos.x < 0 - self.rect.width / 2:
        self.pos.x = WIDTH + self.rect.width / 2

    self.rect.midbottom = self.pos

def animate(self):
    now = pg.time.get_ticks()
    if self.vel.x != 0:
        self.walking = True
    else:
        self.walking = False
    # show walk animation
    if self.walking:
        if now - self.last_update > 180:
            self.last_update = now
            self.current_frame = (self.current_frame + 1) % len(self.walk_frames_l)
            bottom = self.rect.bottom
            if self.vel.x > 0:
                self.image = self.walk_frames_r[self.current_frame]
            else:
                self.image = self.walk_frames_l[self.current_frame]
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.bottom = bottom
    # show idle animation
    if not self.jumping and not self.walking:
        if now - self.last_update > 350:
            self.last_update = now
            self.current_frame = (self.current_frame + 1) % len(self.standing_frames)
            bottom = self.rect.bottom
            self.image = self.standing_frames[self.current_frame]
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.bottom = bottom
    self.mask = pg.mask.from_surface(self.image)

class Cloud(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game):
        self._layer = CLOUD_LAYER
        self.groups = game.all_sprites, game.clouds
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        self.image = choice(self.game.cloud_images)
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        scale = randrange(50, 101) / 100
    self.image = pg.transform.scale(self.image, (int(self.rect.width * scale),
                                                 int(self.rect.height * scale)))
    self.rect.x = randrange(WIDTH - self.rect.width)
    self.rect.y = randrange(-500, -50)

def update(self):
    if self.rect.top > HEIGHT * 2:
        self.kill()

class Platform(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self._layer = PLATFORM_LAYER
        self.groups = game.all_sprites, game.platforms
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        images = [self.game.spritesheet.get_image(0, 288, 380, 94),
        self.game.spritesheet.get_image(213, 1662, 201, 100)]
        self.image = choice(images)
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        if randrange(100) < POW_SPAWN_PCT:
            Pow(self.game, self)

class Pow(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, plat):
        self._layer = POW_LAYER
        self.groups = game.all_sprites, game.powerups
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        self.plat = plat
        self.type = choice(['boost'])
        self.image = self.game.spritesheet.get_image(820, 1805, 71, 70)
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = self.plat.rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.plat.rect.top - 5

def update(self):
    self.rect.bottom = self.plat.rect.top - 5
    if not self.game.platforms.has(self.plat):
        self.kill()

class Mob(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game):
        self._layer = MOB_LAYER
        self.groups = game.all_sprites, game.mobs
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        self.image_up = self.game.spritesheet.get_image(566, 510, 122, 139)
        self.image_up.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.image_down = self.game.spritesheet.get_image(568, 1534, 122, 135)
        self.image_down.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.image = self.image_up
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = choice([-100, WIDTH + 100])
        self.vx = randrange(1, 4)
        if self.rect.centerx > WIDTH:
        self.vx *= -1
        self.rect.y = randrange(HEIGHT / 2)
        self.vy = 0
        self.dy = 0.5

def update(self):
    self.rect.x += self.vx
    self.vy += self.dy
    if self.vy > 3 or self.vy < -3:
        self.dy *= -1
    center = self.rect.center
    if self.dy < 0:
        self.image = self.image_up
    else:
        self.image = self.image_down
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.mask = pg.mask.from_surface(self.image)
    self.rect.center = center
    self.rect.y += self.vy
    if self.rect.left > WIDTH + 100 or self.rect.right < -100:
        self.kill()
```

Comment: where is code ?

Comment: what is `WIDTH` value and `self.rect.width`? I think they are the same

Comment: you need to fix your indentation

Comment: WIDTH is 480, self.rect.width i cant seem to find.. i wrote the program a while ago and cant seem to remember where everything is..

Comment: the indentation on the actual code is right just on here it wouldnt paste right..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is raised because you pass 0 or a negative number to `random.randrange` in line 131 of spritex.py `self.rect.x = randrange(WIDTH - self.rect.width)`. You said `WIDTH` is 480 so `self.rect.width` must be >= 480 in order to raise this error.

If you pass only one argument to `randrange`, make sure that it's a positive integer.

Comment: Thankyou! That makes more sense but i cant seem to find where self.rect.width actually is in the code.. i tried to add 'self.rect.width > 480' but that didnt do anything, I'm sorry i'm not that great at coding and got alot of help with this code

Comment: `self.rect = self.image.get_rect()` creates a [`pygame.Rect`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) instance with the size of the image and the (`topleft`) position (0, 0). So the width of the rect is the width of the `self.image` that you assign here: `self.image = choice(self.game.cloud_images)`.

Comment: Also, remember that you can pass two arguments (start and stop) to `randrange` if you want a random negative number like in the line below: `self.rect.y = randrange(-500, -50)`. I guess that's closer to what you actually wanted to do in the bugged line.

Comment: is the problem with the size of the images i'm trying to add? or is it something else..

Comment: Where exactly do you want the cloud sprites to spawn?